# open ai key integration as a bearer token

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, openai-api, bearer-token

i have made an app in spring boot and there i used jwt security with bearer authentication but now i also want to use openai key which is also integrate with bearer token so i am not able to understand how to have two bearer token for a request as i already have a config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfiguration(JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter) {
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        return security.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/signup", "/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}
```

it is my config file for jwt authorization now how i will integrate apenai key for bearer token

i want to know how to manage this situation where i need to have two bearer token one for jwt and another for openai.